# How do I trigger a "cellClick" event in tabulator from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, tabulator

I hava a page that uses tabulator to make a table. On each row of the table I habe a small thumbnail. When I click on the thumbnail a gallery opens. I want to classify the image by clicking some buttons (yes, no etc). When I click on one buttons I want to close the gallery and then have javascript go to the next cell gallery: trigger a click on the next row's cell. I can get the cell but I cannot manage to trigger the cell click form the javascript portion. I have tried (on the cell I want to use):

```
//inside btn-clicked function
//after closing the gallery just want to trigger default tabulator cellClick event!
cellEl = cell.getElement();
$(cellEl).trigger('click')
```

and

```
$("document").trigger('cellClick', cell)
$("#main-table").trigger('cellClick', [cell])
```

None of these work.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q5fuon6z/

Comment: Please update with some sample HTML as that is likely a key part of any answers here.

Comment: I put a snippet in place to assist you here but it is certainly all wrong and incomplete.

Comment: FWIW your `cell`  here is an extra parameter ref: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/ but probably not what you intended

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem more accurately. I tried with the cell as a param as well.

Comment: FYI your fiddle has `currentRow.getNextRow();` is not a function error....

Answer (score 1):

This is a totally artificial example but this demonstrates a cycle of the children when clicked.

```js
$("#main-table").on('click', '.cell-mate', function(event) {
  let cells = $('.cell-mate');
  cells.toggleClass("occupied next-up", false);
  $(this).toggleClass("occupied");
  let myIndex = $(this).index();
  let clickNext = $(this).index() == cells.last().index() ? cells.first() : $(this).next('.cell-mate');
  clickNext.trigger('cellClick', [$(this), myIndex, clickNext]);
});
$('.cell-mate').on('cellClick', function(event, cell, prevIndex, nextUp) {
  nextUp.toggleClass('next-up');
  $('#monitor').html(cell.html() + " at " + prevIndex + " nudged " + nextUp.html() +
    " at " + nextUp.index());
});
//start it all off (or comment out to start with a user action)
$("#main-table").find('.cell-mate').eq(0).trigger('click');
```

```css
.occupied {
  border: solid 1px #0000ff;
}

#monitor {
  border: dashed 2px #ddffdd;
  margin: 1em;
}

.next-up {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-table">
  <div class="cell-mate">bunk Able</div>
  <div class="cell-mate">bunk Bravo</div>
  <div class="cell-mate">bunk Cat</div>
  <div class="cell-mate">bunk Dog</div>
  <div class="cell-mate">bunk Elephant</div>
  <div class="cell-mate">bunk Giraffe</div>
</div>
<div id="monitor"></div>
```

Here is another example with targets specified as "next".  With this example, it does not matter what order they are in since they specify a target; which I assume exists and did not account for any missing.

```js
$("#main-table").on('click', '.cell-mate', function(event) {
  let cells = $('.cell-mate');
  cells.toggleClass("occupied next-up", false);
  $(this).toggleClass("occupied");
  let mytarget = $(this).data("nextup");
  let nextOne = cells.filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("iam") == mytarget;
  });
  let clickNext = $(this).index() == cells.last().index() ? cells.first() : $(this).next('.cell-mate');
  nextOne.trigger('cellClick', [$(this), $(this).index()]);
});
$('.cell-mate').on('cellClick', function(event, cell, prevIndex) {
  $(this).toggleClass('next-up');
  $('#monitor').html(cell.html() + " at " + prevIndex + " nudged " + $(this).html());
});
//start it all off (or comment out to start with a user action)
$("#main-table").find('.cell-mate').eq(0).trigger('click');
```

```css
.occupied {
  border: solid 1px #0000ff;
}

#monitor {
  border: dashed 2px #ddffdd;
  margin: 1em;
}

.next-up {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-table">
  <div class="cell-mate" data-iam="able" data-nextup="beans">bunk Able</div>
  <div class="cell-mate" data-iam="g" data-nextup="able">bunk Giraffe</div>
  <div class="cell-mate" data-iam="beans" data-nextup="dog">bunk Bravo</div>
  <div class="cell-mate" data-iam="cat" data-nextup="elephant">bunk Cat</div>
  <div class="cell-mate" data-iam="dog" data-nextup="cat">bunk Dog</div>
  <div class="cell-mate" data-iam="elephant" data-nextup="g">bunk Elephant</div>

</div>
<div id="monitor"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this. If i am not mistaken your snippet triggers an event in jQuery and you have another listener for this event on the cells elements, but it does not manage to trigger a click that the tabulator listener listens to, and the code inside the tabulator cellclick function is not triggered

Comment: Your fiddle does not reproduce this issue due to the OTHER noted in the comment `currentRow.getNextRow();` - this throws an error.  I would add your fix for that to a snippet right in your question that fully reproduces the event related (click).  I believe this can be resolved similar to what I have here but I am not familiar with the tabulator code - and that should be added to your question specifically (or as another question if you cannot resolve that error)

Comment: BTW `$("document")` should perhaps be `$(document)` -  but I would recommend you attach that to the outer element that you are calling "table" but feels like a "container" or some such...but splitting hairs on the naming here and I do understand the meaning there.

Comment: Here is the latest fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q5fuon6z/ 
Tabulator vesrion was old in the fiddle. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the correct syntax for tabulator is:

```
 $(cell.getElement()).trigger('click')
```